# Why is it $E[X^2]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx$?

Tags: probability

Why is it $$E[X^2]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx$$ not $$E[X^2]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x^2)dx$$?
I found some books about probability, but there aren'y any explanation regarding the different form of random variables.

Comment: Calculate the expected value for some small finite sample space. See which sum gives you the right answer. (Try the square of the value of a die roll.) Then you will answer your "why" question.

Comment: What is the relation between $X$ and $f$? Please specifiy it! Is $f$ the density of $X$? If yes, try to understand what happens in the case $f$ being supported only in $(-\infty,0)$. E.g. $X$ being uniform on $[-2,-1]$. The squared $x$ in your proposal with $f(x^2)$ takes only values $\ge 0$, so that integral is zero.

Comment: $E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x) f_X(x)\ dx$ by definition. Are you asking why this definition is used instead of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x) f_X(g(x))\ dx?$

Answer (score 2):

There $\mu_X(dx):=f_X(x)dx$ represents the probability measure in $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ when $X$ have a density function $f_X$. In general we have that

$$
\int_{\Omega }g(X)dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\mu_X(dx)\tag1
$$

for any (Borel) measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. In particular the map $g(x):=x^2$ is continuous, so its Borel measurable. The integral $\int_{\Omega }g(X)dP$, when $P$ is a probability measure in $\Omega $, its defined as the **expectation** of the random variable $g(X)$, and denoted by $\mathrm{E}[g(X)]$. Then, by (1), when $X$ have a density function we have that $\mu_X(dx)=f_X(x)dx$ (there $dx$ represents the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$) and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician):
$$
E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)\;dx
$$
where $f$ is the assumed *density* function of the continuous random variable $X$. In your example, $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: The op is asking why is this true . You have are just stating that this is just a law. But the op want's to know why is it like that. So you should provide an explanation

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron: Well, it very much depends on what one means "why" and to what degree one learns probability theory. I have encountered numerous people without math background reading topics such as machine learning. All they need, very often, is a solid reference for well-known results. Besides, why not wait for OP's response to see what they think.